# How to find maximum sum in array less than N

Tags: python, binary

I have array of M elements. I should find maximum sum of my array, which is less than integer number "N". All the elements in array are positive integers bigger or equal to zero. Also, sum can be non-consistent.

FOR example:
let's say `M is = [1,2,3,6,0, 8, 9, 12]` and `N = 20`, so here the answer is 20

but if `M = [1,5,4,6]` and `N = 13`, the answer is 12 - the maximum sum of array which is less than N

Comment: this sum should be consisting of consecutive elements?

Comment: @PratikGandhi NO,

Comment: Is this a subarray (consecutive elements) or subsequence (arbitrary elements)?

Comment: for example if m is [12, 9, 8, 4, 8, 5] and n is 20, the answer will be 20 (12 + 8)

Comment: Are the elements non-negative or can you have both positive and negative elements?

Comment: @DarrylG arbitrary elements

Comment: @DarrylG only positive

Comment: @DarrylG and bigger or equal to zero

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  You should quickly add all the clarifications from the comments to the original question.  Otherwise, a moderator may close it for like of details.  Also if you have any code you have tried that would help keep this as a viable question.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: Find max sum from `weights` array, within `maxCapacity`

**Approach**: Problem is same as 0/1 Knapsack. 
0/1 Knapsack problem: 
Given: `maxCapacity` (int), `weights` (array) and `values` (array). 
Find: max "value" by choosing items with total weight within
maxCapacity.

**In this question**: 
Given: `maxCapacity` (int) and `weights` (array). 
Find: max "weight" by choosing items with total weight within
maxCapacity.

**Difference**:
So unlike knapsack we have to maximise weight
instead of values. Thus, weight array will work as values array here.

```
def func(weights, maxCapacity):
    knapsack = [[0 for i in range(len(weights) + 1)] for j in range(maxCapacity + 1)]

    for w in range(maxCapacity + 1):
        for i in range(len(weights) + 1):
            if i == 0 or w == 0:
                knapsack[w][i] = 0
            elif weights[i - 1] <= w:
                knapsack[w][i] = max(
                    weights[i - 1] + knapsack[w - weights[i - 1]][i - 1],
                    knapsack[w][i - 1],
                )
            else:
                knapsack[w][i] = knapsack[w][i - 1]

    for r in knapsack:
        print(r)

    return knapsack[-1][-1]


func([4, 8, 5, 9], 20)
```

**Summary**: Learn to solve [0-1 Knapsack Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/) to understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to check if the numbers sum is smaller than N, then save the sum as the result and the sum as the string at different lists at the same time.

So when we find the max in the list of sums is smaller than N, we can access the second list containing the strings using the same index.

```py
M = [12, 9, 8, 4, 8, 5]
Ma = []
Ma_num = []
N = 20
for i in M:
    for a in range(len(M)):
        if i + M[a] <= N:
            Ma.append(f"{i} + {M[a]}")
            Ma_num.append(i + M[a])
max_num = Ma_num.index(max(Ma_num))


print(Ma[max_num])
```

Output:

```py
12 + 8
```

By the way, if you meant that you wanted to see the number 20 in output, the solution is this:

```py
M = [12, 9, 8, 4, 8, 5]
Ma = []
N = 20
for i in M:
    for a in range(len(M)):
        if i + M[a] <= N:
            Ma.append(i + M[a])
max_num = max(Ma)
print(max_num)
```

Output:

```py
20
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution, first sum all number in your m array then in a loop check

sum >=n 
if true return m 
else sum = m - min(m)
and remove min
and check again

##############################3

check this solotion

```
M = [1,2,3,6,0, 8, 9, 12]
n = 20
s= 0

while s < n:
    maximum = max(M)
    M.remove(maximum)
    if (s+ maximum)>n:
        continue
    s = s + maximum
print(s)
```

Comment: that is not correct, so if m = [2,5,6,8] and. n = 17, your answer will be 21 - 2 - 5 = 14. but answer is 21 - 5 = 16

Comment: I found another solution check it in my post

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved as a [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

> In the Knapsack problem we have a vector of values (val) and weights (wt)
>
> We want to maximize the sum of a subset of values (val) such that
>
> the corresponding weight is less than some max (referred to as capacity)
>
> We can use the Knapsack algorithm by:
>
> (1) Letting the input array corresponds to both weights and values
>
> (2) Maximum capacity is the max sum

Code for solving Knapsack [from here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/)

```
def knapSack(W , wt , val, n): 

    # Base Case 
    if n == 0 or W == 0 : 
        return 0

    # If weight of the nth item is more than Knapsack of capacity 
    # W, then this item cannot be included in the optimal solution 
    if (wt[n-1] > W): 
        return knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1) 

    # return the maximum of two cases: 
    # (1) nth item included 
    # (2) not included 
    else: 
        return max(val[n-1] + knapSack(W-wt[n-1] , wt , val , n-1), 
                   knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1)) 

def max_sum(K, arr):
  '''Solve using Knapsack code with (set weights and values equal to arr)'''
  return knapSack(K, arr, arr, len(arr))
```

**Test**

```
arr = [1,5,4,6]
print(max_sum(13, arr))
#>>> Outputs 12

arr =[1,2,3,6,0, 8, 9, 12]
print(max_sum(20, arr))
#>>> Outputs 20

arr =  [2,5,6,8]
print(max_sum(17, arr))
#>>> Outputs 16
```

**Complexity**

The time complexity of Knapsack solution is O(nW)

where n is the length of the array arr

W is the max sum

Comment: Dynamic Programming approach should be taken here rather than recursive.

Comment: @VishalSingh -- my post pointed to general Knapsack solutions which shows both recursive and using a table (dynamic programming).  I provided the recursive solution since its the simplest to follow for OP.(i.e. but both recursive and DP solutions are correct)  You should downvote answers only when they are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @DarryIG, can you edit the post a little so I can take back my downvote? Also please emphasize how similar it is to knapsack problem and how you modified same to solve this question.

Comment: @VishalSingh -- I'm not interested in spending more time on this problem to reverse your downvote.  It's especially bad form to downvote competing answers to yours unless they are incorrect.